# how to show the multidimensional array elements using for loop with html tags on a table

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I don't know how to use HTML tag with for loop

```
<?php

    $data [0][0]="Ahmad";
    $data [0][1]=1000;
    $data [0][2]="Kabul";

    $data [1][0]="Refa";
    $data [1][1]=2000;
    $data [1][2]="Ghazni";

    $data [2][0]="Ali";
    $data [2][1]=3000;
    $data [2][2]="Mazar";


    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
    {
       for($j=0;$j<count($data[$i]);$j++)
       {
           echo $data[$i] [$j]." ";
       }
       echo "<br />";
    }

?>
```

So how could I use HTML tag on this code to show the element of the array on a table?

Comment: `<table><tr><td>` are the html tags you need.

Comment: where i should add these tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very basic table structure:

```
echo "<table>";
for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++) {
   echo "<tr>";
   for($j=0; $j<count($data[$i]); $j++) {
       echo "<td>".$data[$i][$j]."</td>";
   }
   echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: If I may answer that ^ Jeff - @RefaGhaznavi See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
    <?php 
$data [0][0]="Ahmad"; 
$data [0][1]=1000; 
$data [0][2]="Kabul"; 
$data [1][0]="Refa"; 
$data [1][1]=2000; 
$data [1][2]="Ghazni"; 
$data [2][0]="Ali"; 
$data [2][1]=3000; 
$data [2][2]="Mazar"; 
Echo '<table>'
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++) {
Echo '<tr>'
 for($j=0;$j<count($data[$i]);$j++) { 
Echo '<td>'
echo $data[$i] [$j]." ";
Echo '</td>'
 } 
echo "<tr/>"; } 
Echo '</table>
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest form you can try:

```
<?php

    $data [0][0]="Ahmad";
    $data [0][1]=1000;
    $data [0][2]="Kabul";

    $data [1][0]="Refa";
    $data [1][1]=2000;
    $data [1][2]="Ghazni";

    $data [2][0]="Ali";
    $data [2][1]=3000;
    $data [2][2]="Mazar";

echo "\n<table><tr><th> Name<th>Number<th>City";
foreach ($data as $item) {
   echo "\n<tr><td>" . implode("<td>", $item);
}
echo "\n</table>";
```

Comment: Side note: The `\n`'s should go at the ends (also).